# How to merge 2 javaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge

I have 2 Arrays.

I want to merge the Field Values from 2nd Array with the 1st Array.

Every value (i.e. "Test") belongs to the Profile Field id listed in the _embedded part of 2nd Array (_embedded.profileField.id).

#### 1st Array: Profile Fields

```
0: Object
field: "FieldLabel1"
id: 1

1: Object
field: "FieldLabel2"
id: 7

2: Object
field: "FieldLabel3"
id: 12
```

#### 2nd Array: Profile Field Values

```
0: Object
id: 1
value: "Test"
_embedded: Object
  profileField: Object
    field: "FieldLabel1"
    id: 1

1: Object
id: 2
value: "links"
_embedded: Object
  profileField: Object
    field: "FieldLabel2"
    id: 7
```

How can I get one Array with both informations together?

Comment: Have you tried to write some code?

Comment: have you tried searching SO?

Comment: do you have some raw example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `map` and `filter` from [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) U can merge this arrays with condition you need. Please see following examples:

```
/* your arrays definition */
var a = [{
  field: "FieldLabel1",
  id: 1
}, {
 field: "FieldLabel2",
 id: 7
}, {
  field: "FieldLabel3",
  id: 12
}
];

var b = [{
  id: 1,
  value: "Test",
  _embedded: {
  profileField: {
      field: "FieldLabel1",
      id: 1
    }
  }
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: "links",
  _embedded: {
  profileField: {
      field: "FieldLabel2",
      id: 7
    }
  }
}];

/* mergedArray contains merged data from two arrays arranged by id */ 
var mergedArray = a.map(function(aItem){ 
  var value = b.filter(function(bItem) {
    return aItem.id === bItem._embedded.profileField.id;
  }).map(function(item){
    return item.value;
  }).pop();
  aItem.value = value;
  return aItem; 
});
```

the result is:

```
margedArray: Array[3]
0: Object
    field: "FieldLabel1"
    id: 1
    value: "Test"
1: Object
    field: "FieldLabel2"
    id: 7
    value: "links"
2: Object
   field: "FieldLabel3"
   id: 12
   value: undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. Can I also display the empty fields where are no associated values?

Comment: yes, U can by iteration on first (`a` in my example) array.

Comment: Updated example for displaying empty fields

Comment: If you want understand `map` and `filter` better try exercises from Jafar Husain - http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

Answer (score -1):

Hi Simply use Jquery see below code!

For Array:

```
var newArray = $.merge(1Array, 2Array);
```

For Object:

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

For array: [jquery merge array](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

For Object: [jquery merge object](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Thanks

Comment: $.merge is jQueery's bloated array.concat - `$.merge(Array1, Array2)` is not much more than `Array1 = Array1.concat(Array2)` done at 1/10th the speed and 10 times the memory

Comment: You think it is not your solution let me remove that answer.